# TortoiseSVN using SSH

Tags: windows, svn, ssh, tortoisesvn, svn-ssh

I'm having this issue when committing to SourceForge using TortoiseSVN:

https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/2636/

The feedback on that page recommends using SSH to get around the problem. So, I relocated my repository to this URL per the recommendation:

```
svn+ssh://mikh2161@svn.code.sf.net/p/datsville/code
```

My username is mikh2161 and the project is called "datsville". When I try to connect it asks me for my password, which I then enter. It seems to work okay. However, the actual commit fails with this error:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Stream doesn't support this capability
Polling for available data on filestream failed: Bad file descriptor
```

Can anyone assist me? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

I'm running Windows 7 Pro x64.

```
TortoiseSVN 1.9.0, Build 26652 - 64 Bit , 2015/08/03 19:33:09
Subversion 1.9.0, -release
apr 1.5.2
apr-util 1.5.4
serf 1.3.8
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
zlib 1.2.8
SQLite 3.8.11.1
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem when I upgraded from TortoiseSVN 1.8.11 to 1.9.0.  Couldn't figure it out so have downgraded back to 1.8.11.

Comment: I confirm that 1.9.0 breaks svn+ssh for me with the same error message. Not sure though, if stackoverflow is the right place to post bug reports for TortoiseSVN. But I did not find a bug tracker for it on sourceforge either.

Comment: I do not see the link to https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/2636/ It seems to be related to big files and otherwise "svn+ssh seems to work without issue"!?

Comment: I have posted a bug report to the TortoiseSVN mailing list: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3131779

Comment: the problem is **caused by svn** (client), see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32138168/2932052).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like svn+ssh support is broken in 1.9.0.
I removed that, and used [1.8.11](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.8.11/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.8.11.26392-x64-svn-1.8.13.msi/download) instead, and it worked.

Comment: I got the same problem and I can confirm older client works. Upgrading the server to 1.9.0 dit not resolve the problem

Answer (score 5):

This problem is **caused by the Subversion client libraries for Windows**. It was introduced with version 1.9.0, and the fix will be released with 1.9.1 <sup>[1] [2]</sup> . So any windows client that is using it will not work with `svn+ssh`. *TortoiseSVN* is just one example, the same was observed with *JavaHL/Subclipse*, *SmartSVN* and the Subversion *command line client* itself.

Update: A **downgrade to version 1.8.12** (which was released along with 1.9.0) helped in my case.<sup>[3]</sup>

---

<sup>[1]</sup> *Subversion Dev*: [JavaHL, 1.9: "Bad file descriptor", "Stream doesn't support this capability" errors](http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/JavaHL-1-9-Bad-file-descriptor-Stream-doesn-t-support-this-capability-errors-tp194133p194383.html)

<sup>[2]</sup> fixed with [r1696225](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1696225) (there is obviously **no bug filed yet**)

<sup>[3]</sup> [TortoiseSVN - Browse Files at SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/)

Comment: Verified: Fixed in 1.9.1 of TortoiseSVN.